# Brew cask install emacs takes control of the emacs command line command

Tags: command-line, homebrew, ui, emacs

I'm currently using Homebrew to install both the command line version of Emacs and the GUI version of emacs, with the following commands:

```
brew install emacs
brew cask install emacs
```

When I first install the command line version, I can launch it via the command line with the command `emacs <filename>`, but after I install the GUI version, using that same command, it causes the GUI version to open.  I would like the command line version to continue to open from the command line command.  I posted this in the [homebrew forum,](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/launch-emacs-command-line-over-emacs-gui-version-from-terminal/6369/2) but the only answer I was given was to check my shell config file.  I'm on macOS Catalina, so I'm assuming `.zshrc` is the file, but this contains nothing relating to Emacs at all.  Any suggestions for how to keep the GUI version from being launched from the command line command would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you run `emacs -nw` on the command line?

Comment: @jksoegaard, it opens the command line version!  Is there a way to set this to the default?

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer with instructions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an alias in zsh that invokes `emacs -nw` whenever you write `emacs`. The `-nw` argument means to start emacs in "non-windowed" mode - i.e. a command line text interface.

You can create the alias by editing the `.zshrc` file you mention, and add the following line:

```
alias emacs="emacs -nw"
```